# infinite dimension representations of an abelian group

Tags: representation-theory

How do you show that an abelian group has no irreductible infinite dimension representation? Is it only true for a locally compact group?

The only proof I found myself is to study maximal ideals of the group C*-algebra. Do you know a simple proof without operator algebras theory?

Answer (score 3):

Let $K=\mathbb{C}(t)$, the field of rational functions.

Then $K$ is an infinite dimensional irreducible complex representation of the multiplicative group $K^\times$.

Comment: Thanks for the example! The standard proof of this result for finite-dimensional representations (i.e. using Schur's lemma) requires finding eigenvalues, which can always be done because of the algebraic closedness of $\mathbb{C}$. Of course, in the infinite dimensional situation this is no longer the case.